# Paypal Button and CF7 Form

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, contact-form-7

i'm using a Wordpress CF7 form that redirects to a Paypal form on form submit, using the Additional Settings. I've added a function in there that works well. At the same time, a new post is created using the info from the CF7 form. So, the post is created whether or not the Paypal is paid or not.

```
on_sent_ok: 'my_redirect();'
```

How would i go about adding the new post ONLY after and if the Paypal is paid. Can i pass the form values through to Paypal then send them back for submission if payment is successful.

```
<script>
function my_redirect() {
 var price = document.getElementById('total').value;
 var taxed = document.getElementById('taxed').value;
 var revised = (parseInt(price)/100) * parseInt(taxed);
 var url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=EMAILHERE&lc=GB&item_name=PRODUCTNAMEHERE&amount='+revised+'&currency_code=GBP&button_subtype=services&no_note=0&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHostedGuest';
    window.location = url;
    jQuery("#totals").val(revised);
 }
</script>
```

Not really sure where to start using the basic button/email solution given by Paypal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: put that code in the success url where you will get redirected after being paid. put the function creation on that page and check paypal status which gets returned. if true then the function will be created. or paypal will redirect to not success page

Comment: hope you get what i tried to say, its a basic flow but the code has to be done by.

Comment: Could you revise my code a little bit to give me a start in the right direction. Sorry, struggling to see what you mean. Thanks for your help though!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i will give you the steps

1. the paypal button is clicked and the user goes to paypal site and pays and the paypal returns the user to a success page which you create.
2. in that page put that function to create what you want.
3. if the user doesnt pay the function will not be created and even it will not be created if payment fails

hopw you understand

Comment: But what if my price is calculated from the form fields/options?

Comment: but you said the post will be created only when the ONLY after and if the Paypal is paid.

Comment: The fields are completed. One of the fields has a price calculator. This is sent to Paypal via jQuery. Could i add a function in my Paypal code to update_post_meta if payment was successful?

Comment: yes you can do that too. but the best way is you check if the paypal returns a success response then only you create a post

Comment: ok - how do i check to see if payment was successful then (success response)

Comment: Search for PayPal success response. And how to get it. You will understand